# Running multiple Tasks reuse the same object instance

Tags: c#, concurrency, task

Here's an intersting one. I have a service creating a bunch of `Task`s. At the moment only two tasks are configured in the list. However, if I put a breakpoint within the `Task` action and inspect the value of `schedule.Name`, it is hit twice with the same schedule name. However, two separate schedules are configured and in the schedule list. Can anyone explain why the Task reuses the last schedule in the loop? It this a scope issue?

```
// make sure that we can log any exceptions thrown by the tasks
TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += new EventHandler<UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs>(TaskScheduler_UnobservedTaskException);

// kick off all enabled tasks
foreach (IJobSchedule schedule in _schedules)
{
    if (schedule.Enabled)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                                {
                                    // breakpoint at line below. Inspecting "schedule.Name" always returns the name 
                                    // of the last schedule in the list. List contains 2 separate schedule items.
                                    IJob job = _kernel.Get<JobFactory>().CreateJob(schedule.Name);
                                    JobRunner jobRunner = new JobRunner(job, schedule);
                                    jobRunner.Run();
                                },
                                CancellationToken.None, 
                                TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, 
                                TaskScheduler.Default
                                );
    }
} // next schedule
```

Comment: Looks like a closure variable you're looping over. Try assigning schedule to a temp variable inside the loop and use that one.

Comment: Seems closure issue, try out declaring Task's local `IJobSchedule capturedSchedule = schedule;` and use it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use a temporary variable inside the foreach loop, it should solve your issue.

```
foreach (IJobSchedule schedule in _schedules)
{
    var tmpSchedule = schedule;
    if (tmpSchedule.Enabled)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                                {
                                    // breakpoint at line below. Inspecting "schedule.Name" always returns the name 
                                    // of the last schedule in the list. List contains 2 separate schedule items.
                                    IJob job = _kernel.Get<JobFactory>().CreateJob(tmpSchedule.Name);
                                    JobRunner jobRunner = new JobRunner(job, tmpSchedule);
                                    jobRunner.Run();
                                },
                                CancellationToken.None, 
                                TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, 
                                TaskScheduler.Default
                                );
    }


} //
```

For further reference about closures and loop variables, see 
[Closing over the loop variable considered harmful](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx)